# Kafka halting because log truncation is not allowed for topic error shuttng down kafka nodes

Tags: apache-kafka

We are facing an issue with our kafka set up as we see our Kafka nodes goes down showing this error every couple of days.

```
 Halting because log truncation is not allowed for topic __consumer_offsets, 
Current leader 11's latest offset 123 is less than replica 13's latest offset 234 .
```

Every-time there is new topic mentioned in the error log.
We have 3 Kafka nodes with 3 zookeeper nodes.
Could you what is causing this issue and how it can be fixed.

This is the code which checks for this error

```
 /**
 * Unclean leader election: A follower goes down, in the meanwhile the leader keeps appending messages. The follower comes back up
 * and before it has completely caught up with the leader's logs, all replicas in the ISR go down. The follower is now uncleanly
 * elected as the new leader, and it starts appending messages from the client. The old leader comes back up, becomes a follower
 * and it may discover that the current leader's end offset is behind its own end offset.
 *
 * In such a case, truncate the current follower's log to the current leader's end offset and continue fetching.
 *
 * There is a potential for a mismatch between the logs of the two replicas here. We don't fix this mismatch as of now.
 */
val leaderEndOffset: Long = earliestOrLatestOffset(topicPartition, ListOffsetRequest.LATEST_TIMESTAMP)

if (leaderEndOffset < replica.logEndOffset.messageOffset) {
  // Prior to truncating the follower's log, ensure that doing so is not disallowed by the configuration for unclean leader election.
  // This situation could only happen if the unclean election configuration for a topic changes while a replica is down. Otherwise,
  // we should never encounter this situation since a non-ISR leader cannot be elected if disallowed by the broker configuration.
  if (!LogConfig.fromProps(brokerConfig.originals, AdminUtils.fetchEntityConfig(replicaMgr.zkUtils,
    ConfigType.Topic, topicPartition.topic)).uncleanLeaderElectionEnable) {
    // Log a fatal error and shutdown the broker to ensure that data loss does not occur unexpectedly.
    fatal(s"Exiting because log truncation is not allowed for partition $topicPartition, current leader " +
      s"${sourceBroker.id}'s latest offset $leaderEndOffset is less than replica ${brokerConfig.brokerId}'s latest " +
      s"offset ${replica.logEndOffset.messageOffset}")
    throw new FatalExitError
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Is parameter `unclean.leader.election.enable` set to `true` or `false`?

Comment: I set it true as node was not coming up after multiple restart

Comment: Did `unclean.leader.election.enable=true` solve the problem for you?

Comment: yes it worked but whenever we reverted this property nodes worked for some time and then went down again. We are trying to investigate what is causing this issue is there some problem with  kafka or it is zookeeper

Comment: @viren I am facing same issue. Did you figured out what was the cause? and what is the correct way to fix it?

Comment: isn't this `Current leader 11's latest offset 123 is less than replica 13's latest offset 234 . ` quite indicative of what needs to be done? Why not shift the replica's latest offset to 234 or the replica's latest offset to 123?

Answer (score 2):

This happens with `0.10.0` and occurs even with `min.insync.replicas=2`.

The leader of a partition writes to followers before committing itself (especially for topics with `acks=all` like `__consumer_offsets`). When a short network interruption occurs, the follower might recover fast and before messages are written to the leader and therefore the replica halts due to unclean leader election. This was a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1211) that has been fixed on `0.11.0`.

One possible solution would be to set `unclean.leader.election.enable=true` for topics like `__consumer_offsets` and then restart the brokers. According to [Kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/),

> **`unclean.leader.election.enable`**: Indicates whether to enable replicas not in the ISR set to be elected as leader as a last resort,
>   even though doing so may result in data loss.

When a broker crashes, the leader partition will be switched by the Controller that will also choose one replica in ISR as the partition leader. If no replica is available, then you won't be able to write to or read from that partition. 
By setting `unlcean.leader.election.enable` to `true`, the first replica which is available, will be elected as the partition leader even if it is not in ISR and therefore, some messages might be lost!

However, in order to solve this issue I would suggest to upgrade to a more stable version (if you are still using 0.10.0).

Comment: We are at 0.8.2 upgrading this would be a prod release which we can not afford right now. Right now this setting is true for all could you please suggest what could be impact of using unclean.leader.election.enable=true in production env

Comment: @viren See my updated answer that includes the impact of `unclean.leader.election.enable`. Hope it helps.

Comment: i checked Kafka 0.11.3 code and found this check is still there which will cause kafka service shutdown network issue can happen anytime in any application so could you please how it will solve this error. I have pasted code from 0.11 version in question

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous can you share the link which discuss about the order in which kafka commits message.("The leader of a partition writes to followers before committing itself"). I referred to kafka design document but didn't find any reference. As per producer config : request.required.acks, -1 means The producer gets an acknowledgement after all in-sync replicas have received the data.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous from kafka documentation : Followers consume messages from the leader just as a normal Kafka consumer would and apply them to their own log. Having the followers pull from the leader has the nice property of allowing the follower to naturally batch together log entries they are applying to their log.  A message is considered "committed" when all in sync replicas for that partition have applied it to their log. https://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html#replication

Comment: "This was a known issue that has been fixed on 0.11.0."
I am getting this error even on 0.11

Comment: faced this issue in kafka 1.1.1, setting unclean.leader.election.enable to true and restarting helped!

Comment: I am usgin kafka 2.0.0, and still facing the same issue.