# Kafka broker are keep on restarting?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, apache-zookeeper

I have 4 kafka brokers and 3 zookeepers deployed upon kubernetes. Out of 4 only 2 kafka brokers are working and rest 2 keep shutting down and restart with below error:

```
Exiting because log truncation is not allowed for partition byfn-sys-channel-0, current leader's latest offset 2 is less than replica's latest offset 21 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
```

Below is the config of kafka

```
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT zookeeper0:2181,zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181
KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE    false
KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES   103809024
KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS   1
KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES 103809024
KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS  -1
KAFKA_LOG_DIRS  /var/kafkas/kafka2
KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR    3
KAFKA_BROKER_ID 2
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS  PLAINTEXT://kafka2:9092
```

Please let me know how can i fix this ?

[Kafka halting because log truncation is not allowed for topic error shuttng down kafka nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036973/kafka-halting-because-log-truncation-is-not-allowed-for-topic-error-shuttng-down)

Above link shows if log truncation is not allowed for a topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka halting because log truncation is not allowed for topic error shuttng down kafka nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036973/kafka-halting-because-log-truncation-is-not-allowed-for-topic-error-shuttng-down)

Comment: link mentioned by you for log truncation for topic not partition